# A matter of completeness and preference relations

Tags: preferences, self-study

I have a question about preference relations and completeness.

Prove that:

i) There exists a complete relation $\succcurlyeq$, such that $\sim$ is not complete.

ii) There exists a complete relation $\succcurlyeq$, such that $\succ$ is not complete.

I tried work on top of the definitions of the relations, but to no avail.

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Take your favorite utility function. Chances are, the preferences represented by it are the desired counterexample for both problems.

Comment: A complete relation $R$ is one where for all $a,b$ you have $a\,R \,b$ or $b \, R\, a$ (possibly both)

Answer (score 2):

Usually one defines $a \sim b$ if $a \succeq b $ and $b \succeq a$ and one defines $a \succ b$ if $a \succeq b$ and not $b \succeq a$.

Now assume there are only two alternatives $a$ and $b$.

1. If $a \succ b$ then $\sim$ is not complete as neither $a \sim b$ nor $b \sim a$
2. If $a \sim b$ then $\succ$ is not complete as neither $a \succ b$ nor $b \succ a$.